# Android ListView performLaunchActivity error doesn't show xml layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

ı'm fetching data from database via SQLite. ı recorded data to the database and with Listview ı wanna show the data in a xml. but couldn't launch activity. ı am using Listview for the first time. thank you for your helps.

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2180    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5039    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

here is the java code;

```
public class ButceGetirenListView extends ListActivity {

    Spinner yil,ay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        yil=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerYillar);
        ay=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAylar);

        String[] result=getiren();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.butcegetir,result));

        ListView listV=getListView();
        listV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView)arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });
    }
    protected String[] getiren(){

        int yillar=Integer.valueOf(yil.getSelectedItem().toString());
        String aylar=ay.getSelectedItem().toString();
        TemporaryDatabase tdb=new TemporaryDatabase(this);
        tdb.open();
        String[] result=new String[25];
        result = tdb.getDataHesapla(yillar,aylar);
        tdb.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

and xml code:

```
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Please See my answer and comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
yil=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerYillar);
ay=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAylar);
```

However, nowhere in your XML file do you have two Spinners with those IDs. Infact, you never even call `setContentView()` to use your XML file.

Due to this, `yil` and `ay` are null and will result in a `NullPointerException` when you try to use them in the `getiren()` method.

To fix this, add the spinners to your layout, and call `setContentView()` before using `findViewById()`. You will also need to add a ListView with the following ID:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

So that the `ListActivity` can find a `ListView` with a custom custom layout.

**Example**

```
<YourBaseLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
    <TextView />
    <firstSpinner />
    <secondSpinner />
</YourBaseLayout>
```

Comment: There are other files. Spinners are there . But how will ı user Listview in xml . Can you write it here

Comment: There may be other files, but you still have to set them as the View for your Activity.

Comment: Yes ı set them as the view. But not this xml. in another xml.is  there ay difference between this or another.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occur because you are forgot to write `setContentView();` line.

**Solution:-**

Write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` this line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and before `yil=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerYillar);` this line in onCreate() method, it will solve  your problem.

Comment: I wrote but  still same exception

Comment: @hopeTo Don't extend listactivity, only extend activity and define listview in xml file and then try.

Comment: when ı use activity it gives  error. because of setListAdapter

Comment: @hopeTo you can not use setListAdapter() method with simple activity, use ArrayAdapter or Base Adapter for this.